# The difference between Swift's instance methods and type methods

Tags: class, swift

I'm new to Swift programming (I have web language experience like HTML/CSS, JS, Jquery, PHP, etc). I'm going through the Apple documentation and various online resources, but I can't seem to find the answer to my question which is: What is the difference between instance methods and type methods in classes?

I understand the syntax of writing both, and how to use both, but I'm unsure of when it would be better to use one over the other? Is there a reason you'd want to call a method in a class without creating an instance of said class? I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around a practical example of one's use over the other.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class method is useful when you want to connect some kind of functionality to a class without forcing the client to instantiate that class, and when a method doesn't depend on the state of a particular object.

In an object-oriented approach to programming they are often used in place of traditional utility-style functions, which take some sort of input and return output without referencing a particular object, e.g., an HTTP routing system with class methods "Post" and "Get" that takes a url and query parameters as arguments and sends a request to the server. These functions are useful across a range of different classes and don't necessarily need to be represented by an underlying instance variable.

They can also be used to include comparison functions where both objects are of the same class. Say you're trying to calculate the dot product of two matrix objects--it doesn't make sense to prefer one object as the basis on which to compare the other and not the other way around--especially since calculation of a dot product has no consequences for either underlying matrix object. The preferred solution then is something like:

```
 class func dotProduct(a: Matrix, b: Matrix) -> Double
```